# Can I configure Salt to send emails to 2 targets for Sensu?

Tags: salt-stack, sensu

I'm configuring Sensu via Salt. Below is my `sensu.sls` file.

As you can see below, it sends emails to `alert@mydomain.com`. However I want it to send these emails to another email address too. Am I allowed to put 2 email addresses on that line? How do I separate them? Can you please show me a sample?

```
mailer-ses:
  mail_to: 'alert@mydomain.com'
  mail_from: 'alert@mydomain.com'
  aws_access_key: 'BLAHBLAHBLAH'
  aws_secret_key: 'BLAHBLAHBLAH2'
  aws_ses_endpoint: 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
```

Comment: Have you tried comma separated addresses? Read the actual ruby file here: https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-mailer/blob/master/bin/handler-mailer-ses.rb. Unfortunately I don't know ruby but if comma separated does not work I don't think anything will. The other option is to have a forwarding email address.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
  mailer-ses:
      mail_to: 
        - 'alert1@mydomain.com'
        - 'alert2@mydomain.com'
      mail_from: 'alert@mydomain.com'
      aws_access_key: 'BLAHBLAHBLAH'
      aws_secret_key: 'BLAHBLAHBLAH2'
      aws_ses_endpoint: 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
```